# How to Chnage dropdownlist value style based on it's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using `Kendo UI` in `Asp.net` Webforms. I am in a situation where I need to differentiate data that is coming from tables. I want to differentiate the styles of each value based on data.

Example

```html
Value                               |PrimaryOwnerId
_______________________________________________________________________
EVP-RP&P                           |  False
Execution Coordinator                   |  False
Inspection Lead                           |  False
Instrument, Electrical, and Analyzer      |  False
Logistics                           |  True
Operations                           |  False
Planning                           |  True
```

this table I'm binding with kendo dropdown and whatever values have `primaryownerId` false I want to apply bold font style and other need to be Italic fonts.

```html
function loadValues(PrimaryOwners1, PrimaryOwners2) {
    $("#lstPOwner1").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: PrimaryOwners1,
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        change: function () {
            disablecontrol(this.value(), "#btnFilter1")
        }
    });
}
```

[image: This are the data I am binding with the dropdownlist]

Please, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use kendo templates to achive this

```
var data = [
  {flag: true, value: 'test1'},
  {flag: false, value: 'test2'},
  {flag: true, value: 'test3'},
  {flag: false, value: 'test4'}
]

$('#dropdownlist').kendoDropDownList({
  dataSource: data,
  dataTextField: "value",
  template: '<span style="#= flag ? "font-weight:bold" : "font-style:italic" #">#:value#</span>'
});
```

Try it in dojo https://dojo.telerik.com/AKAteWoY/2